# Fit div inside page without scrolling

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I have created layout with flexbox and vuetify, where card contains header and footer, and scrollable content between them.

Here is current code in codepen:

https://codepen.io/peter-peter-the-typescripter/pen/poyZmEm?editors=1010

I need fit card (including paddings of container) in height to remove scrollbar of main page. Can you tell me how to edit code to ensure that? Thank you.

[image]

code:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid style="height: 100%;">
      <v-row style="height: 100%">
        <v-col>
          <v-card>
            <v-row no-gutters style="height: 100%">
              <v-col class="no-gutters red" style="height: 100%; max-height: 100vh; flex-direction: column; display: flex;" cols="4">
                <!-- header -->
                <div style="flex-shrink: 0">
                  <v-toolbar>
                    <v-toolbar-title>
                      Toolbar Left
                    </v-toolbar-title>
                  </v-toolbar>
                </div>
                <!-- Scrollable area -->
                <div style="flex: 1; overflow-y: auto;">
                  <v-list>
                    <template v-for="item in 30">
                      <v-list-item :key="item">
                        <v-list-item-content>
                          <v-list-item-title v-html="'title ' + item"></v-list-item-title>
                        </v-list-item-content>
                      </v-list-item>
                    </template>
                  </v-list>
                </div>
                <!-- footer -->
                <div style="flex-shrink: 0">
                  <v-btn>Click me</v-btn>
                </div>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the container's vertical paddings, and minus them to your `max-height: 100vh` on your `<v-col/>`. If the container's has a padding of `12px` both at the top and at the bottom, your max-height should be `max-height: calc(100vh - 24px)`.

```html
<v-col
  ...
  style="max-height: calc(100vh - 24px);"
>
...
</v-col>
```

[image]

On an additional note and not really related to my answer, you can use Vuetify's [flex utility classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#flex) so you don't need to have inline flex styles.

Here's a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-yonath-fjtq8?file=/src/components/Playground.vue). I cleaned it up a bit and removed extra styles and elements.

Comment: Hi, thank you, this solution works but is not very flexible in my option because I always need decrease height by height of all components which I added in vertical direction, is there some dynamic way of it?  :/ But anyway thank you for answer I add you upvote

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on the Codepen. The scrollbar is still showing however it is deactivated, I am not sure if this is exclusive to Codepen or would be in other cases.

You need to give the `.container` or `.container--fluid` and `.col` a `padding: 0`. It is the vertical padding that is causing the issue.

Alternatively if you want to do it in the HTML, simply add the `p-0` class to the `container` and `col`.

Your updated Codepen can be found [here](https://codepen.io/EGxo/pen/RwaeavQ).

Comment: Hello, thank you for effort but point is that I need this padding on container. Check please added image, I need that card will be floating in center with this padding

Comment: Hi @DenisStephanov. I am not experienced with the library you are using but it seems similar to Bootstrap. You need to add some gutters to the column. Based on your image your col should be a `col-4` with a gutter of 4 on the left and a gutter of 4 on the right. For the vertical padding you can set your card to have a margin-top and bottom of for example 10vh, and a height of 80vh.

Comment: I am primary backend developer, I just need solve this. It will be totally fine if you help me  with raw styles. I then replace it with vuetify's classes if it will be possible